# SSRS 2008 R2 crashes on clicking next page

Tags: reporting-services

SSRS 2008 R2 crashes on clicking next page

Hi, I am facing a straing issue in SSRS, I Have a report which is having multiple pages

Reports loads successfully

On clicking Priview report loads

Report has 67 pages

pageing works fine till page 12

Trying to load page 13 , SSRS crashes

Trying to load page 14 , works fine.

I cahnged the SP to eturn only page 13s data.. hence now Report is having only one page ..

Report load successfully, Preview successful, Export successful.

Again I chaned the SP to return Page 12, 13 ,14 data --> now Report has 3 pages 1, 2, 3

--> Report lodes successfully, Preview Page 1 Success, Preview Page 2 --> SSRS crash --> Reopen the solution --> Preview Page 2 successful, --> Export to Excel --> SSRS crash.

Please help me out in this strange issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would completely ignore the BIDS / Visual Studio Preview pane as it is riddled with bugs and inconsistencies and proves nothing (assuming your end users aren't using Visual Studio).

Instead I would deploy the report for each test run to a test environment / folder on the host server (Report Manager / SharePoint). As well as being a realistic and meaningful test, this has many advantages such as being able to leave multiple IE tabs open with various parameter combinations set, then just refresh them after a Deploy to retest.